# Error when version upgrade in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter,android

I can't understand.

Error has occured, when I upgrading version in 'pubspec.yaml'

version: 1.0.1+2 was no problem. build done!

but, 1.0.2+3, 1.0.3+4, .. ERROR!!!! build failed!!

even though 1.0.0+1.. error too..

What should I do?

[no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oapuw.png)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKR9V.png)

error info is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, but link was error page(404)

Comment: Oops, Here's the link: https://medium.com/@nabil6391/solutions-to-flutter-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-1d2c36b2001a

Comment: oh.. I found the page! I solve it! Thanks!!!!